# cmake target_link_libraries() cannot find renamed lib target by set_target_properties(archive_output_name)

Tags: c++, cmake

RT~ ps: `cmake version 3.9.2`

My codebase just like this.

```
suzanwen@n224-004-133:~/repos/C++/ttt:)$ tree -L 2
.
├── build
│   ├── bin
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── lib
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── test
│   └── thirdparty
├── build.sh
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Makefile
├── test
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cc
└── thirdparty
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── gflags
    └── hellolib

10 directories, 9 files
```

my thirdparty/hellolib/CMakeLists.txt is

```
PROJECT(hello)

SET(LIBHELLO_SRC hello.cc)
MESSAGE(STATUS "LIBRARY PATH=" ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})

ADD_LIBRARY(hello_static STATIC ${LIBHELLO_SRC})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hello_static PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME "hello")
```

my test/CMakeLists.txt is

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/hellolib
                    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/gflags/include)

IF(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH)
  LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})
ENDIF(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.cc)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main hello)
# TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main hello_static)
```

when I build my top-level project, an error occurs like this.

```
/usr/bin/c++    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cc.o  -o ../bin/main  -L/home/suzanwen/repos/C++/ttt/build/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/suzanwen/repos/C++/ttt/build/lib -lhello
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhello
```

But when I comment the line `# SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hello_static PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME "hello")` and `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` with `hello_static`, everything goes fine.

It seems that `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` cannot find renamed lib target. Could anyone explain it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` cannot find renamed lib target.

Setting `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME` property renames not a **target**, but an output *file*. So linking with a *target* still works:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main hello_static)
```

One cannot rename the target once it is created, but it is possible to create ALIAS for a target:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(hello ALIAS hello_static)
```

After that it is possible to link with the alias:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main hello)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I've tried with `ADD_LIBRARY(hello ALIAS hello_static)`, seems that cmake still output `libhello_static.a` instead of `libhello.a`. So that is to say, a **target** name and its **output filename** may not be consistent, right? And we still link library with **target**.

Comment: "target name and its output filename may not be consistent, right?" - Yes, **filename** perfectly may be different from the **target**. CMake supports linking both with a **target** and with a **file** (if there is no target with given name). When link with a **file**, you need either to pass its absolute path or use `link_directories()`. When link with a **target**, CMake *automatically* transforms it into linking with a *file*, so this is preferable way in most cases.